# How can i solve the incompatible types error?

Tags: java, types, incompatibletypeerror

I try to add a list of things inside an array
   **

```
public Wrap(String name, Wrap wrap, List<Things> things) {
        super(name);
        this.bread = bread;
        **things.addAll( Arrays.asList( things ) );**
    }
```

**

and I get this error:
incompatible types. Required `Collection<? extends topping>` but 'asList' was inferred to `List<T>` :no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that `List<topping>` conforms to Topping

Comment: You're misunderstanding `Arrays.asList`.  You already have a list.

Comment: Why are you adding a collection to itself?

Comment: are you sure that you don't actually want to write `this.things.addAll(things)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) on `things`, which is already a `List`. You can simply call `addAll()` directly with `things`:

```
public Wrap(String name, Wrap wrap, List<Things> things) {
    super(name);
    this.bread = bread;
    things.addAll(new ArrayList(things));
}
```

However this doesn't make much sense to add `things` to `things`. Perhaps you have a class variable `things` and meant to use the `this` keyword?

```
this.things.addAll(things);
```